# How do i repeat data in Microsoft excel in relative with variable?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, export-to-excel

Hi I have a List of names and a variable, i need an excel formula or Add-on or an automated method to repeat the names based on the number in the variable.
I need a formula to automate Output column,
eg:

[image: I need a formula to automate Output]

Comment: Does it have to be a variable or would a VBA user-defined function be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Probably as clean as I can make it. There is a `For` loop and `Do Until` loop to give you options.

```
Sub repeat()
    ' define varible types
    Dim i, n As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    ' initialize variables
    n = 1
    i = 1
    
    ' do loop until empty cell is found in column 1 (A)
    Do Until IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 1))
        ' second loop to define number of iterations
        For n = 1 To ws.Cells(i, 2)
            ' find last row to keep adding to the bottom of the list
            LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            ' populate list
            ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, 3) = ws.Cells(i, 1)
        Next
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was a great puzzle to do without VBA.
Solved it by making index column, repeat column and iteration column...Then do some vlookup and hlookup stuff. Should be noted that Vlookup needs to be a sorted list to work.
Here is a link to my example where I tried to [show you.](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlJPzN_hrX36iqkGcqYojyZ77Kho4Q?e=P3S85y)
[image]